# Microsoft Access: Long Text field truncated in report! How to fix this?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I created a simple report in Access. One line per record (using the default tabular format with Report Wizard). However, one text field is sometimes too long and is truncated when one record is displayed on only one line.

How do I tell Access that when the text field is too long, display it (and the record) in more than one line as needed so that the complete text is shown? Thanks.

More info: I tried to increase the height of the text field, but then every record in the report had its height increased whether needed or not. This wasn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`CanGrow` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194664.aspx) of the text field to True.
This will increase the field height only in the lines where it's really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [MS Office Support Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-the-field-size-HA010274716.aspx#BM3) [Refer the part `Change the field size of a text field`]

> 1. Right-click the table that contains the field that you want to
>      change, and then click **Design View**.
> 2. In the table design grid, select the field for which you want to
>      change the field size.
> 3. In the **Field Properties** pane, on the **General** tab, enter the new
>      **field size** in the Field Size property. You can enter a value from 1
>      to 255. This number specifies the maximum number of characters that
>      each value can have. For larger text fields, use the Memo data type.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Should be fine now, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Long text fields in queries can be truncated and right justified.
Right click, in design view select properties in the column of the query and set format to rich text and the text is no longer truncated at 255 characters.
Format with cstr([FieldName]) to return a long text field left justified.

Answer (score 0):

New comment on an old problem, but another way MS Access can truncate data on a form is related to formatting. Default format for some text fields is "@", which means the text will be processed. For MEMO/LongText fields that means truncation is possible. Remove the "@" format to eliminate textual processing.